# Python call by reference issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

As what I have understand on python, when you pass a variable on a function parameter it is already reference to the original variable. On my implementation when I try to equate a variable that I pass on the function it resulted empty list.

This is my code:

```
#on the main -------------
temp_obj = []
obj = [
    {'name':'a1', 'level':0},
    {'name':'a2', 'level':0},
    {'name':'a3', 'level':1},
    {'name':'a4', 'level':1},
    {'name':'a5', 'level':2},
    {'name':'a6', 'level':2},
]

the_result = myFunction(obj, temp_obj)

print(temp_obj)
#above print would result to an empty list
#this is my problem

#end of main body -------------


def myFunction(obj, new_temp_obj):
     inside_list = []
     for x in obj[:]:
         if x['level'] == 0:
              inside_list.append(x)
              obj.remove(x) #removing the element that was added to the inside_list

     new_temp_obj = obj[:] #copying the remaining element 

     print(new_temp_obj) 
     # the above print would result to
     #[{'name': 'a3', 'level': 1}, {'name': 'a4', 'level': 1}, {'name': 'a5', 'level': 2}, {'name': 'a6', 'level': 2}]

     return inside_list
```

Am I missing something or did I misunderstand the idea of python call by reference?

Comment: Use `list(obj)` instead of `obj[:]` . It looks nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python is not pass-by-reference. It is pass-by-object.**

Consider the following two functions:

```
def f(mylist):
    mylist = []

def g(mylist):
    mylist.append(1)
```

Now let's say I call them.

```
mylist = [1]
f(mylist)
print(mylist)

mylist = [1] # reset the list
g(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

What would the output be?

If Python were **pass-by-value**, the functions would take a copy of the list, so modifying it would not affect the original list once you return out of the function. So in both cases, you would be printing the original list, `[1]`.

If Python were **pass-by-reference**, the functions would accept a reference to the object and modifying it would modify the actual object that the reference references, so the first output would be `[]` and the second, `[1,2]`.

If you run this example, you will find that the first output is `[1]` (the list if unaffected) and second output is `[1,2]` (the list is affected).

**O_O**

When you do `new_temp_obj = obj[:]`, Python is constructing a *new* object `obj[:]` and giving it the name `new_temp_obj`.

If you were to `append`, Python would look for the thing called `new_temp_obj` and add elements to it. The argument you passed in tells it where to look for the list.

**You are creating a totally new object at a totally new location in memory and  simply giving it the same name,`new_temp_obj`**

Comment: Thank for explaining well. It helps me a lot and understand something new. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help! If you still have questions, [here](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) is a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_temp_obj = obj[:] #copying the remaining element
```

This would make `new_temp_obj` reference to another new list object. You could use `id` to see that its `id` changes with this assignment.

Change it to:

```
new_temp_obj[:] = obj[:]
```

You'll see your expected result.